# Photoplethysmogram sampling frequency problem

Tags: mimic-iii

I'm doing some calculations on the photoplethysmogram signal it seems that the metrics I'm using suffer from a cyclic artifact each 94-96[s].

The waveform seem ok at the "breakpoints".

Is it possible that photoplethysmogram signal was sampled with a different frequency and then interpolated to 125 Hz?

Is it possible that the interpolation was applied on data chucks of 94-96 [s]?

Answer (score 5):

There is a known issue with the PPG signals in the MIMIC II/III
waveform database, although I don't know whether this is the same
issue as what you're seeing.

The issue we've seen is that the PPG seems to run "slow" compared to
the other signals.  For example, if you measure the pulse transit time
(the difference in time between the start of the QRS complex and the
start of the following PPG pulse), you will see that it gradually
increases over a period of about 80 to 100 seconds, then abruptly
jumps backwards.  If you plot the PTT over a long period of time, it
will show a "sawtooth" pattern with an amplitude of about 40
milliseconds.  This pattern is certainly an artifact of the data
collection process, not a physiological effect.

Here's an example of what this looks like:
[image: Graph of pulse transit time computed from MIMIC II record 3013448_0085, exhibiting a sawtooth pattern]

Our best guess about why this happens is that the sampling rates for
the signals are not equal.  The ECG, we know, is sampled at
approximately 499.76 Hz (and then "peak-picked" to 124.94 samples per
second.)  Other signals (such as ABP) are sampled at 124.94 Hz.  If
the PPG, on the other hand, were sampled at 125 Hz, it would drift
relative to the ECG by about .48 milliseconds per second, which is
consistent with the slope of the "sawtooth" pattern we observe.  So my
guess is that the bedside monitor has an internal buffer which is
being *filled* (by the A/D converter) at 125 Hz, but is being
*emptied* (by the data archiving software) at 124.94 Hz; and
periodically, when the buffer gets too full, the archiving software
jumps ahead by a few samples in order to re-synchronize.  I should
emphasize that this is all conjecture; we don't know any details about
the hardware or software implementation of the monitor.

As you say, I haven't seen any obvious artifacts in the PPG signal
that would indicate the precise moment where this jump occurs, and in
fact the jump in PTT is not always perfectly abrupt from one beat to
the next, which makes me think that perhaps it's not instantaneous,
but rather, the monitor interpolates the transition somehow in order
to make the waveform look smooth.